# What is a cheap (read free) way to send notification emails on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer, delayed-job, background-process

I'm building a web app that sends notification emails when a user's post gets a new comment, or if the user gets mentioned.

I am using Postmark along with ActionMailer to send out emails, so in my comments controller whenever a new comment is created, that action triggers Mailer to deliver an email. The thing is, this is not as quick as I expected and delays the response--when a user posts a comment, he doesn't immediately get the reaction via ajax but waits until the controller finishes sending the mail.

So naturally I decided to try background processing with delayed_job. Well, this does work, and now I get immediate response when I post a comment. However, I just realized that to run delayed_job on Heroku I need to manually launch a worker dyno, and once it's up, it stays up until I scale it back down. And this seems to cost some money.

I want to try this while spending as less money as possible, and searched around to see if there were any solutions. I did find a solution called HireFire, that automatically launches your dyno when there's work to do, and shuts it down when there is no work to do (https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire) but this solution charges for the service, which although is cheaper than nothing but still beats my original purpose.

I'm even thinking about just going without delayed_job and sacrifice response speed, at least until I see any traction with the site.

So I am wondering, is there any solution (or hack) that lets me send notification emails on Heroku for free? Or do most people who build sites that do something like this just pay for the extra worker dyno?

Or, would it be OK to just go without background processing ActionMailer actions at least in the beginning? (I am not sure how much load this has on the entire server, for example if ten people comments on something simultaneously if this will affect the performance for the rest of the site users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hirefire should be the best for you. I think you can use it for free, it's open source, but dunno the requirements to run it.

Another solution might be the add on iron worker. They give you 25h/month worker time for free.

Answer (score 3):

IronWorker should fit your needs well here. (Note that I work for Iron.io.) No need to manage servers. Just create workers, upload them to IronWorker and then run immediately or schedule them for later -- IronWorker has some flexible scheduling options. As mentioned in another post, a good amount of hours come per month come free.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need real-time, i.e. you are happy with a 10 minute delay, you could just use the Heroku Scheduler.  Run a task every 10 minutes that kicks through your current job queue, then dies until the next 10-minute iteration.

Not free, but not as much as queuing up a worker either.